# expose enum in WCF to be consumed by Client. WCF/C#/VS-2008

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

This is my starting point [link text](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/0002f271-1418-4027-b19a-3820702fc22f.aspx) to expose an enum which the Client can consume; it is not part of method signature. My code compiles but I am unable to view it in `wsdl` and unable to use it in my C# windows form application test project. Is the test code in the link missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`KnownType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute on an existing data contract.

```
[KnownType(typeof(YourEnum))]
[DataContract]
public class FooContract { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The link, [link text](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/0002f271-1418-4027-b19a-3820702fc22f.aspx),that I was following gave this code

```
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(EnumHelper))]
```

If I changed it to this

```
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(MyEnumName))]
```

My consuming client is able to view the enum type. The ? is why doesnt the helper static class assist in exposing the enum. I even came across this [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx)